# update columns based on id pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

df_2:

```
order_id   date        amount name   interval is_sent
123        2020-01-02  3      white  today    false
456        NaT         2      blue   weekly   false
789        2020-10-11  0      red    monthly  false
135        2020-6-01   3      orange weekly   false
```

I am merging two dataframes locating when a date is greater than the previous result as well as looking to see if a data type has changed:

```
df_1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['date'])
df_2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['date'])
res = df_1.merge(df_2, on='order_id', suffixes=['_orig', ''])
m = res['date'].gt(res['date_orig']) | (res['date_orig'].isnull() & res['date'].notnull())
changes_df = res.loc[m, ['order_id', 'date', 'amount', 'name', 'interval', 'is_sent']]
```

After locating all my entities I am changing changes_df['is_sent'] to true:

```
changes_df['is_sent'] = True
```

after the above is ran changes_df is:

```
order_id   date        amount name   interval is_sent
123        2020-01-03  3      white  today    true
456        2020-12-01  2      blue   weekly   true
135        2020-6-02   3      orange weekly   true
```

I want to then update only the values in `df_2['date']` and `df_2['is_sent']` to equal `changes_df['date']` and `changes_df['is_sent']`

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `update` with `set_index`

```
cf = changes_df[['order_id','date','is_sent']].set_index('order_id')
df_2 = df_2.set_index('order_id')
df_2.update(cf)
df_2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_2
   order_id        date  amount    name interval is_sent
0       123  2020-01-03       3   white    today    True
1       456  2020-12-01       2    blue   weekly    True
2       789  2020-10-11       0     red  monthly   False
3       135   2020-6-02       3  orange   weekly    True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df3 = df2.combine_first(
    cap_df1).reindex(df.index)
```

This is my solution